# how to store check box value from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

i have two activity with checkboxs in a list and i have to pass each value of checkbox to another activity and make it checked, where i can't use intent to pass that because both activity is not next together.

In this case how i will store the values in an array and to retrive in another activity

thanks to all, i have done it now and i'm posting it.

```
         int i = 0;
        checkBox = new CheckBox[getItemPR.size()];
        Constants.INDEX_TEMP_NEW=new int[getItemPR.size()];// stoing in array[]
        while (i < getItemPR.size()) {

            ITEM dtItem = getItemPR.get(i);

            TableLayout table11;
                table11 = (TableLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                        R.layout.itemoverview2, null);
                checkBox[i] = (CheckBox) table11.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                checkBox[i].setId(i);
                checkBox[i]
                        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(
                                    CompoundButton buttonView,
                                    boolean isChecked) {

                            onSetcheckboxchanged(buttonView.getId());                               
                            }

                        });
                if (Constants.INDEX_TEMP_NEW[i] == 0) {
                    checkBox[i].setChecked(true);

                } else {
                    checkBox[i].setChecked(false);
                }
```

and

```
    public void onSetcheckboxchanged(int k) {

        if (checkBox[k].isChecked()) {              
            Constants.INDEX_TEMP_NEW[k] = 0;

        } else {
            Constants.INDEX_TEMP_NEW[k] = 1;
        }       
}
```

Comment: will you use shared preference for storing check box values..

Comment: @Tamilarasi Sivaraj i have to store the checkbox value with id so in another activity if the list have same details of that list and if the checkbox is checked here also it has to be checked.

Comment: can you post your code what you tried so far?

Comment: check my answer, you can hold all ids in arraylist and set that list to App class, then get that list of ids anywhere and used/ make checked...

Comment: have you tried to get the child view from the list view then  get and store the checkbox values in araylist?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a static class/methods for this kind of thing, utilising `SharedPreferences`

```
public static class Hal {
    private static final String PREFS   = "com.xxx.xxx.xxx";

    public static String getPreferenceString(Context ctx, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Hal.PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
    }

    public static void setPreferenceString(Context ctx, String key, String val) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Hal.PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor preferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        preferencesEditor.putString(key, val);
        preferencesEditor.commit();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a singleton class to store the value of the array.
eg. 'Storage' class with has the getter, setter of an array. You can set the data here in the class:

```
public class Storage { 
private static Strorage strorageData = new Strorage ();
public static synchronized Strorage getInstance() {
        if (strorageData == null) {
            strorageData = new Strorage ();
        }
        return strorageData ;
    }
    // getter & setter

}
```

In your activity you can access the object of this class using

```
     private Storage storageData;
 storageData = Storage .getInstance();
```

In this get the data by using getter.

Comment: i have to store the checkbox value with id so in another activity if the list have same details of that list and if the checkbox is checked here also it has to be checked.

Comment: make a 2D arrayList with id(int) and value(boolean) in Strorage class. Is that what u are asking?

Comment: public class Storage{

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {  //setter
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {   //getter
       return name;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Create one java class which will extends to Application class, and get the object of that class by calling **App.getInstance()** and then you can set or get your selected list item from any activity.

```
public class App extends android.app.Application {
private static App app;
private ArrayList<Integer> checkedItemList;
private Activity activity;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    app = this;
}

public static App getInstance(){
    return app;
}

public void setCheckedItemList(ArrayList<Integer> checkedItemList){
    this.checkedItemList = checkedItemList;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getCheckedItemList(){
    return this.checkedItemList;
}
}
```

Now register the Application class in Android Manifest.xml under **application tag**

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to store checkboxs value in it, i am new to android

Comment: If you are using ListView with multiple choice then get the selected item and set that list to that class...